# On button click execute method or function on 'this' in Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, methods, addeventlistener

I'm trying to make a simple web app in order to learn objects. Basically, you click a button and it'll generate a stopwatch. You can make as many as you like. Every button click will also instantiate a new object with its own id, seconds, minutes, and hours.

The problem is that each stopwatch should have its own button. When you click on the button, the associated stopwatch should start the timer. I can't seem to figure out a way that on button click, it would execute the method `tick()`:

```
//Class based objects ES6
class Timer {
    seconds: number;
    minutes: number;
    hours: number;
    id: string;

    constructor(id: string) {
        this.seconds = 0;
        this.minutes = 0;
        this.hours = 0;
        this.id = id;
    }

    tick() {
        setInterval(() => {
            this.seconds++;
            const timerId = `timer${this.id}`;
            const timerDisplay = document.getElementById(timerId)!;
            timerDisplay.textContent = this.seconds.toString();
        }, 1000)
    }
}

//Different approach to executing tick
function tick(timer: Timer) {
    setInterval(() => {
        timer.seconds += 1;
        const timerId = `timer${timer.id}`;
        const timerDisplay = document.getElementById(timerId)!;
        timerDisplay.textContent = timer.seconds.toString();
    }, 1000)
}
```

I've been playing around with two different `tick()` functions to try and get it to work. Once I get one to work, I'll delete the other `tick()` function.

Here is the part of the code that creates new stopwatches in case its needed:

```
const addButton = document.querySelector('.add-button')!;

addButton.addEventListener('click', createTimer);
document.addEventListener('click', startTimer);

var timers: Timer[] = []

function createTimer() {
    // Create a new Id and instantiate new Timer object
    const id = document.getElementsByClassName('timer').length || 0;
    const nextId = (id + 1).toString();
    var timer = new Timer(nextId);
    timers.push(timer);
    
    // Create the elements of a timer
    const timerContainer = document.createElement('div');
    const timerHeader = document.createElement('h1');
    const timerDiv = document.createElement('div');
    const startBtn = document.createElement('button');    

    // Fill in the default text of the above elements
    timerHeader.textContent = 'Timer';
    timerDiv.textContent = '00:00:00';
    startBtn.innerText = 'click me'

    // Link timer element with Timer object using the same Id
    timerDiv.id = `timer${nextId}`;
    timerDiv.className = 'timer';

    // Append elements to parents
    timerContainer.appendChild(timerHeader);
    timerContainer.appendChild(timerDiv);
    timerContainer.appendChild(startBtn);

    document.body.appendChild(timerContainer);
}

function startTimer() {
    // How do I get the function to execute tick() and know what 'this' is supposed to be?
}
```

The problem I am trying to get my head around is when I use an addEventListener to call the `startTimer()` function, it should call the tick() methods and know which stopwatch its associated with. But I can't figure out a way where tick() can be called and still know what 'this' is referring to.

Comment: If you move the creation of the timer into the class, the scoping issue disappears: https://jsfiddle.net/mkhfs16p/

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG. Wow your example simplified my code by alot. I never knew it was possible to put the button and the method itself inside the constructor.

Comment: @MisterJojo thanks. Yeah I'm aware of the time drift that can happen if I do seconds++. It was just a way for me to visualize things. I think the var timers: Timer[] = [] was just a typescript thing.